# How to call powershell script with configfile,parameters in c#

Tags: c#, powershell

I am new powershell script in c#. I have a powershell script file ps.ps1 and powershell settingfile ConsoleSettings.psc1

```
C:\Windows\system32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe -psconsolefile "D:\e\ConsoleSettings.psc1" -noexit -command ". 'D:\e\ps.ps1'"
```

run it and get  "

> Get-RST -SearchRoot 'erd/user' -PasswordNeverExpires:$false
>   -PasswordNotChangedFor 60   -enabled

my function result correctly.

Now, i want to get this result in c# . My code  is;

```
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            RunScript(LoadScript(@"d:\e\ps.ps1"));
        }


        private string RunScript(string scriptText)
        {
            PSConsoleLoadException x = null; ;
            RunspaceConfiguration rsconfig = RunspaceConfiguration.Create(@"d:\e\ConsoleSettings.psc1", out x);
            Runspace runspace = RunspaceFactory.CreateRunspace(rsconfig);
            runspace.Open();
            RunspaceInvoke runSpaceInvoker = new RunspaceInvoke(runspace);
            runSpaceInvoker.Invoke("Set-ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted");
            Pipeline pipeline = runspace.CreatePipeline();
            pipeline.Commands.AddScript(scriptText);

            pipeline.Commands.Add("Get-RST -SearchRoot 'erd/user' -PasswordNeverExpires:$false -PasswordNotChangedFor 60   -enabled");            
Collection<PSObject> results = pipeline.Invoke();

            runspace.Close();
            StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
            foreach (PSObject obj in results)
            {
                stringBuilder.AppendLine(obj.ToString());
            }
            return stringBuilder.ToString();
        }

        private string LoadScript(string filename)
        {
            try
            {
                using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(filename))
                {
                    StringBuilder fileContents = new StringBuilder();
                    string curLine;
                    while ((curLine = sr.ReadLine()) != null)
                    {
                        fileContents.Append(curLine + "\n");
                    }
                    return fileContents.ToString();
                }
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                string errorText = "The file could not be read:";
                errorText += e.Message + "\n";
                return errorText;
            }

        }
```

And then i have a error : **the term  "Get-RST -SearchRoot 'erd/user' -PasswordNeverExpires:$false -PasswordNotChangedFor 60   -enabled" is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.**

How to solve this problem, or how to call powershell script with configfile, parameter like (Get-RST -SearchRoot 'erd/user' -PasswordNeverExpires:$false -PasswordNotChangedFor 60   -enabled)  in c#

please help me...

Comment: `return File.ReadAllText(filename)`

Comment: İ dont understund clearly, i do this loadscript function return value, but the same problem continue, i take problem in invoke step 'Collection<PSObject> results = pipeline.Invoke();'

Answer (score 0):

You are adding your command line as a Command rather than a script. Commands are intended for  things like cmdlets or functions without parameters. You will use the additional methods to add the parameters. A simple solution would be to just use `AddScript` again.

```
pipeline.AddScript("Get-RST -SearchRoot 'erd/user' -PasswordNeverExpires:$false -PasswordNotChangedFor 60   -enabled");
```

Comment: Hi Adam, i added like a script but i have the same problem, same error.